# Netbeans Connection to SQLSERVER still not wroking

Tags: java, sql-server, netbeans

I am still facing this problem for about 2 days already. It seems I did some researched on Google and as well stack overflow. I followed step by step but still not running.

> -> Enable SQL BROWSER
>
> -> Enable TCP/IP PORT and change to 1433

I tried both but still not working. It still giving me this error.

> Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host ., named instance sqlexpress has failed. Error: "java.net.UnknownHostException: .". Verify the server and instance names, check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434, and for SQL Server 2005 or later verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.

This is my connection code:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://.\\sqlexpress;user=sa;password=;database=pharmacy_posic");
```

My server name: .\sqlexpress

My Username : sa

My password : (blank)

Am I making any mistake on the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this it is explained very well:

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z46OHxdEEEI